# How many threads should I create in my case?

Tags: java, multithreading

I searched in Google for a solution but I'm still a bit confused about how many threads I should use in my particular case.

I have two usages of threads. First, I have a folder with 10 files in it which I want to parse in parallel (independent of each other). Second, I have a shared data object on which 100 tasks run. Each tasks consists of reading the data object and writing to a shared structure (HashMap).

Should I use only as many threads as CPU cores? Or should I use a ThreadPoolExecutor with a minimum number of threads equals 2 and a maximum number equals 999 (then 100 threads are created)?

Comment: Rule is simple: thread count = resource unit count. For heavy calculation, unit is a processor core, for DB operations -- DB connection, etc.

Comment: Consider using 2 executors: first for file read/parse, where you experimentally chose most effective thread count, second for computation tasks, where tread count = cores minus one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider use of [`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`](https://goo.gl/9esEKA). This creates a thread pool with as many threads needed and reuse idle threads.

I can't tell you how many threads will be created for your 100 tasks. If task is long to execute, 100 threads will be created to start all tasks in parallel immediatly. If task is very short or if you don't push all tasks at the same moment, first thread will be reused for executing more tasks (and not only one).

By the way, creating a thread implies some cost (cpu and memory) and too many threads can be useless due to limitation of number of cores. In this case, you can also limit the number of threads using [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool( int nThreads )`](https://goo.gl/4M3Bti).

A widespread practice is use of `number of cores x 2` for the thread count

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two small following up quesitons. First, should I destroy the threadpool after the operation and create a new one next time or should I keep it throughout the lifetime of the application? Second, how can I make the main thread wait until all jobs in the threadpool have finished?

Comment: @machinery After creating the executor service, add task by calling `submit()` method. Don't care of threads lifecycle, the executor service do that for you. At the end of your main method, call `executorService.shutdown()` method to stop the service (submitting task is no more allowed and threads will exit when no more task in queue). You can add a call to `awaitTermination()`  to block main thread until all tasks finished

Comment: Thank you again. The awaitTermination() only works after a shutdown request, otherwise it waits forever. What I was asking for was to wait for all tasks to complete before shutdown (somewhere in the middle of my program). How can this be done?

Comment: @machinery For your use case... submitting a task into the executor service returns a `Future`. You can check is task is terminated by calling `isDone()` or you can call `get()` to wait for this task termination. So, to wait for all tasks, you should keep a reference on this futures objects for all submitted tasks and wait for termination of each where you need in the middle of your program

Answer (score 0):

The ThreadPoolExecutor is only a higher level way to apply multithreading the substance don't change, but it's use can be helpful in the management.

There is no real rules all depends on the type of processing, IO, sync/async tasks involved.

Normally for batch processing for evaluate the number of needed/optimal threads I start with a number of thread == number of CPU then by trial I estimate if can be benefical increase them, depending on the type of tasks involved a slightly higher number of threads (than the number of cores) can be benefical to performance

For example you can try starting with 1.5*cpu tasks verifying the performance difference with 1*cpu and 2*cpu

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Using Executors is recommended as in that case you shall have a minimum threshold for creation of threads and threads will be reused otherwise creating separate threads for each task may result in creation of too many threads.